# How to work around multiple inheritance missing in c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oop, inheritance

I have a POCO class generated by entityframework for my users:

```
public partial class AppUser : BaseEntity
{
    public int User_Id { get; set; }
    public string SpecialProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I have a fancy authentication provider project that implements AspNet Identity and has a MyIdentityUser class that inherits from IdentityUser provided by microsoft.

```
public class MyIdentityUser : IdentityUser<int, MyIdentityUserLogin, MyIdentityUserRole, MyIdentityUserClaim>
{
     .... (needs the properties of appuser around here) ...
     .... (need the properties of IdentityUser around here too) ...
}
```

Now because I want to use my fancy auth provider in multiple projects, I need to pass in the "actual type" of the object in the db store - so that non nullable fields etc can be filled in.

The class MyIdentityUser needs the properties of the POCO class so that those properties are retrieved from the db, and new records are created correctly, and it needs the properties of IdentityUser to work with microsoft's aspnet identity implementation.

I was hoping to be able to write the below statement so that i can pass in the type to use:

```
IdentityProvider<AppUser> provider = new IdentityProvider<AppUser>();
```

But my problem is that - my AppUser class inherits from BaseEntity, and the MyIdentityUser has to inherit from IdentityUser, so it cannot extend AppUser.

How can I work around this problem, without:

1) Tightly coupling the auth provider with the EF type?

2) Rewriting all the POCO properties into a hardcoded interface in the project, and inheriting from that (the properties are driven from a database first EF)

I've tried to add the POCO class as a property of the MyIdentityUser, but then the entityframework part of aspnet identity doesnt work, because you may not use Generics.

I'm stuck, and I think I'm missing something at a conceptual level. Happy to provide more details as needed..

Comment: Why make your `AppUser` inherit from `BaseEntity` instead of just using `MyIdentityUser` and adding it's properties in there?

Comment: I don't "make it" per se, it comes from entityframework, and the T4 template generates it like that. My problem is that I have a generated class on the one hand, and a microsoft class on the other that i cannot edit, my new class MyIdentityUser needs the properties of both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used nhibernate in a project with a similar issue and what I ended up doing was implementing IUser in my models.  Here Id is in BaseModel

```
public class ModelClass : BaseModel, IUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    string IUset<string>Id { get { return this.Id.ToString(); } }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: so, how did you pass IUser to the code base that needed it?

Comment: hmm thinking about it a bit more, this could probably be the only way to do it. unless creating a type at runtime is possible.

Comment: IdentityUser is the default implementation of IUser in EntityFramework but it does not mean you cannot implement it yourself and use that instead.  ASP.NET Identity expects an IUser and it will use your object, Entity Framework expects your entity which works in both cases.